# JQuery - on() click doesn't work 2nd time round

Tags: jquery, onclick

I have tried multiple ways to get this working, but no matter what I change, it just doesn't work.  It works perfectly on the first link that is selected.  Any subsequent links that are selected it doesn't work and I get no errors due to it loading to a new page.

```
        // get discounts for store 
        $('.store_link a').on('click', function(e) { 
            alert('yeah');
            var $this = $(this);
            var cat = $this.attr('data-cat');
            var $optionSet = $('.categories > .option-set');
            var storeDiscountURL = $this.attr('href');
            var storeID = '.' + $this.attr('id');
            //select relevant filter colour
            $optionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $('#nav li.' + cat + ' a').addClass('selected');
            selector = '.second_page,' + storeID;
            loadMoreItems(storeDiscountURL, 'secondpage', selector);

            //remove infinate scroll 
            $container.infinitescroll('destroy');

            return false;

        });

 echo "<div id=\"toggle-$id\" class=\"contenthover hide\">";

                                      echo "<p class=\"store_link\"><a id =\"skid_$discount[skID]\" data-cat=\"$category\" href=\"index.php?curr=$_SESSION[curr]&skid=$discount[skID]\">View all discounts for this store</a></p> ";


                                </div>";
```

Comment: Are you adding links dynamically?

Comment: Have you check the error in browser console (it is available in tools or pressing by 'ctrl+shift+j' ?

Comment: the right way of using *on* is: `$('.store_link').on('click', 'a', function(e) {`

Comment: Are your other links using the "store_link" class?

Comment: If the class "store_link" is applied directly to your "a" tag, try using "$('a.store_link')"

Comment: Yes @SaravanaKumar, they are dynamically added.  All my links have store_link class.  Ive tried using the other suggestions but still no joy.  I therefore assume SaravanaKumar is onto something...

Comment: Ive added the HTML which is added dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, the clicking link TAG is adding or getting updated by other JS or jQuery plugins in any way. So, the selector is not working for the subsequent **'A'** tags. You should try:

```
$('body').on('click', '.store_link a', function(e) { 
    ....
    ....
});
```

The selector **'body'** should be any closest selector which is always present while it's first DOM load time.